# How to merge existing objects as @OneToMany relation in new entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to update an existing `@OneToMany` entity without fetching it before? (*merge*) in context of a parent entity?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_address_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_addres"))
    private Address address;
}


@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id; //asume I can control the id

    private String city;
    private int zip;
    private String street;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Person> persons;
}
```

In DB exists an address with `id=12`.

Now I'm trying to assign this address to a `new Person()`, but without fetching the address entity from DB. Is it possible that the `address` will be getting merged by hibernate in context of the person?

```
@Transactional
public void create() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setId(12); //exists in DB
    address.setCity("test");
    person.setAddress(address);
    dao.merge(person);
}
```

Result: `SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505 - UniqueConstraintViolation - duplicate key "12" in address`.

Answer (score 1):

If you waant assing address with 12 as id, you must get it from database and then assign it...

```
@Transactional
public void create() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Address address = dao.getAddressByID(12);
    person.setAddress(address);
    dao.merge(person);
}
```

Otherwhise you are creating a new address with the same ID, so you can't do in way as specify in your question...

Comment: Yes, the question is if hibernate is capable of detecting that the address (by its `id`) already exists and auto-merges it, without having to fetch the address-entity beforehand?

Comment: @membersound try to use PERSIST cascade : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade But I think it works only with fetch from DB

Comment: Casacade.ALL implies PERSIST!